# Why doesn't PostgreSQL combine two indexes in this example?

Tags: postgresql

I'm creating a snapshot of an order book from "order book events". The essense of the task is demonstrated by the example below:

```
CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT i.event_id, 10000*(round(i.event_id/10000,0)+1) AS last_event_id  FROM ( SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,1000000) AS event_id ) i;

ALTER TABLE t ADD PRIMARY KEY (event_id);

CREATE INDEX t_idx ON t USING btree  (last_event_id ASC NULLS LAST);

EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM T WHERE event_id <= 80001 and last_event_id >= 80001;
```

The output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` is as follows:

```
                                                QUERY PLAN                                                     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Index Scan using t_pkey on t  (cost=0.42..2928.77 rows=73870 width=9) (actual time=52.526..52.529 rows=2 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (event_id <= 80001)
  Filter: (last_event_id >= '80001'::numeric)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 79999
Planning time: 0.211 ms
Execution time: 52.578 ms
```

Thus PostgreSQL uses only t_pkey index and ignores t_idx.

Why doesn't PostgreSQL uses both t_pkey and t_idx?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6 on Centos 7

Comment: It's planner calculation - two use both indexes it must do bitmap index scan which in this case probably have bigger cost. Try it yourself by setting `set enable_indexscan = false` and rerun the query.

Comment: @JustMe Thanks! It is clear how to move forward now

Comment: Sidenote: after changing a table definition or adding indexes, you should always run `VACUUM ANALYZE` on the table(s). `(cost=0.42..2928.77 rows=73870 width=9) (actual time=52.526..52.529 rows=2 loops=1)`

Comment: @wildplasser Only a functional index will profit from an `ANALYZE`. You are right for `ALTER TABLE` though.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe :I get different estimates after running VACUUM ANALYZE(but stilll the same plan) After changing the `last_event_id`to ` 1*(round(i.event_id/1000,0)+1) AS last_event_id` , PG picks a differernt plan,but only after  ANALYZE.

Comment: If the statistics change, the estimates change. But a `CREATE INDEX` won't change the estimates unless it is an index on an expression.